# Are the spaces below homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that $$X=\{(x, y)\in\mathbb R^2: 0<x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$$ is homeomorphic to $$Y=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2=1, 0<z\leq 1\}?$$ I was supposed to show it but I can't see geometrically why they would be homeomorphic.

Comment: Geometrically, $X$ is just a punctured disc, and in $Y$, the puncture is spread out to a full circle. It's not obvious, a priori, that these would yield homeomorphic spaces; certainly their closures in their respective ambient spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: What? No, the boundary of the circle in $X$, where $x^2+y^2=1$, will correspond to $z=1$ in $Y$, and the puncture of the circle in $X$, where $x^2+y^2=0$, will correspond to $z=0$ in $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

Each point in a disc of radius 0< r<=1 in X could be associated with a point in a disc of the cylinder Y at height 0< r<=1:

In X you have x=rsin(alpha) and y=rcos(alpha) , where 0< r<=1.

So in Y you could have z=r; x = sin(alpha); y=cos(alpha)

So the spaces are homeomorphic

Answer (score 1):

The first set $X$ is a puncture disk.
The second set $Y$ is a cylinder.  You can see that a cylinder is homeomorphic to an annulus. Now imagine pulling the middle of the annulus together until only a point is missing.

To be formal you could use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tips above I got:

In polar coordinates:

**(i)** $X=\{(r, \theta); r\in (0, 1], \theta\in [0, 2\pi]\}$,

**(ii)** $Z=\{(1, \theta, z): \theta\in [0, 2\pi], 0<z\leq 1\}$.

The map $f:X\longrightarrow Z$ defined by $$f(r, \theta)=(1, \theta, r)$$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Think about cone V with vertex u. Then V can be viewed as a disk. When you removed vertex u then it is homeomorphic to X. In addition V-{u} is homeomorphic to Y,hence Xis homeomorphic to Y.